# Как вывести панельку подсказки под текстовым вводом в HTML?

Tags: html, позиционирование

У меня есть  `<input type="text" />`. Когда пользователь вводит буквы в этот инпут я хочу отображать по мере ввода текста подсказки. Это поиск пользователей на сайте, и те пользователи имена которых содержат введеный текст должны быть показаны прямо под полем ввода.

Не могу понять как в HTML сделать так что-бы список с именами пользователей появлялся прямо под текстовым полем ввода, при этом что бы остальная страница не уезжала вниз. То есть он должен висеть поверх остальной информации но находиться строго под текстовым полем.

Кроме того само текстовое поле находится в блоке который при определённом scroll-е position:fixed а при определённом в обычном позиционировании.
Надо что бы при любой прокрутке подсказки оставались ровно под полем ввода.

Comment: Может код покажете, чтобы было понятнее чего Вы хотите.

Comment: @Дмитрий Полянин А вы не рассматривали возможность воспользоваться готовым плагином autocomplete из jquery например? https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так чтоли?

```css
.search {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
}

.search input {
  width: 250px;
  height: 24px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #E0E4E8;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.find {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background: #FFF;
}

.founded {
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #E0E4E8;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -1px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  transition: .2s ease;
}

.founded:hover {
    background: #F0F4F8;
    transition: .2s ease;
}

.search input:valid + .find {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю<br>
Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю<br>
<div class='search'>
  <input type='text' placeholder='Поиск' required>
  <div class='find'>
    <div class='founded'>1</div>
    <div class='founded'>2</div>
    <div class='founded'>3</div>
  </div>
</div>
Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю<br>
Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю<br>
Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю<br>
Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей чаю<br>
```

Comment: О, супер, спасибо, заработало! Только не могу понять почему find аккурат под input попал? Или абсолютное позиционирование привязывается точкой начала к точке где в обычном позиционировании должен начинаться очередной эллемент?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, Если указать родителю `position: relative`, а ребёнку `position: absolute`

Comment: Но он разьве тогда не в начало родителя прицепится? А начало родителя оно в верхнем левом углу текстбокса. А он прицепился к нижнему левому углу.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, потому что `position: relative` для `input` наследуется от `search`

Comment: Почитал по этой теме и так понял что если top и left не заданы, то позиция автоматически начинается с того места где элемент должен находится в обычном потоке. Если написать top и left в 0 тогда сразу в начало родителя смещается.